# Codeigniter override own controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I´m working on an application which is deployed at different locations.

Depending on the location, some functionality in some controllers/models/views work differently, is there a way to override/extend this classes? (I don´t want to change the code base directly as it will lead to problems in future releases)
I´m looking for a way similar to the MY_ override of core classes/functions.

As I can´t show the actual code, here is a simple example of what I would like to achieve:

The normal basic controller, used as is in most deployments:

```
class SomeController extends CI_Controller {
    ...
    public function index() 
    {
        $data['var'] = 10;
        $this->load->view('someview',$data);
    }
    ...
}
```

And here is how a special controller for just on location could look like:

```
class SomeController extends CI_Controller {
    ...
    public function index() 
    {
        $data['var'] = 5;
        $this->load->view('someview',$data);
    }
    ...
}
```

(in this case, the only change is in the var value)

Comment: You might want to show some code and explain what _"some controllers work differently"_ means?

Comment: It´s just, that some functions will have some differnt results - depending on parameters I can predict that they will change (so puting everything in config files isn´t a solution)

Comment: That doesn't help us at all. What methods are you talking about? What are the situations this could happen in? What "different results" do you mean? Please update your question with _some real info_.

Comment: Have you tried extending core class in codeigniter, as documented [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html?highlight=core#extending-core-class) ?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson I added a simple example

Comment: how about using environment variable? I think it's a good option if you don't want to change your application code for every different deployment

Comment: `Depending on the location`: what does that mean? a different url, a different login or what?

Comment: location in this case is a physical independent installation with own database, data, and code.

Answer (score 0):

If you only are changing the variables then instead of overriding your class based on the `location` (a.k.a independent environment), try using environment variables. For this, I would recommend using the [DotEnv](https://packagist.org/search/?tags=dotenv) library via composer

```
composer require vlucas/phpdotenv
```

Once it is installed, add this into your `index.php` at the bottom before loading the bootstrap file

**index.php**

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
...
```

Once that is setup, you can use the `getEnv()` function to retrieve the variables:

**.env Example**

```
CONTROLLER_VAR=5
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
...
```

**SomeController**

```
class SomeController extends CI_Controller {
    ...
    public function index() 
    {
        $data['var'] = getEnv("CONTROLLER_VAR");
        $this->load->view('someview',$data);
    }
    ...
}
```

*Also make sure Composer is autoloaded.*